# Integrate non-wordpress site into a wordpress site

Tags: customization, third-party-applications

I am investigating a project where a site that has already been built needs to be integrated into a wordpress site that is currently under development. Essentially the preexisting site consists of two sections / pages.  The first is a simple list with links to the second which is an interactive chart.  FWIW that stack was developed using Angular JS on the client.

Both sides are cooperating / in partnership, so some work can be done on each side.

I suspect I could try some sort of iframe type of plugin, or perhaps a custom page hosted off of the same server as the wordpress site.

Honestly I know little about WP and am just looking to get pointed in the right direction.  Anything is appreciated.

Comment: You can just use templates, they can be entirely custom code and you assign a "page" in the administrator section to them: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use PHP.

   `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('wp-load.php');`
2. You can use another language: http://wp-api.org/
3. You can use [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
4. Or you can use WordPress and just integrate what you have into it, http://codex.wordpress.org/